# Ubuntu failed first bootup

Tags: boot

I successfully installed Ubuntu but when I rebooted to load up the very first time my PC reached `Verifying DMA Pool Data` and then stayed there for almost 30m before I gave up on it.

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 R2

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and have some suggestions regarding to your problem.

1. If you just install new hardware such as ram, network card or hard disk on your computer, try remove them and restart your computer.
2. Enter bios and please make sure your hard disk is selected as the primary boot. To enter bios, you need to press delete key the moment you boot up your computer(Based on your motherboard). You can find it on youtube on how to access the bios.
3. Try clearing your CMOS memory by removing the CMOS battery in your pc for 10 seconds and put it back. Then restart your computer

I hope this will help

Comment: Tried that but there was no change. When I reverted to a image I made before the ubuntu install it worked flawlessly.

Comment: So now you can boot your windows? Do you wish to dual boot your computer?

Comment: I did a format and install for ubuntu, before doing that I made an image of my windows 10 in case something went wrong.
I installed Ubuntu and then did the reboot for first boot up. Got the message. After waiting I loaded my Reflect and restored windows by CD using it. It booted up with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just given up.
Maybe if I change hardware someday I will try again.